# Error : Unable to run the app with Firebase jar included

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, proguard

### Gradle Output:

```
:app:proguardRelease
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
Warning: com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Category
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Hierarchy
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Hierarchy
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Hierarchy
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.shaded.apache.log.Logger
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
Warning: org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent
Warning: there were 73 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
    If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
    the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
    (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
:app:proguardRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.727 secs
```

---

When run on Device, app crashes when tapped on the Chat tab in the app..

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PUBLIC_ONLY
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:243)
            at com.d.a.a.c.f.ae.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at com.d.a.a.c.z.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.e.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at com.woodpeck3r.janasena.app.Views.c.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.r.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.r.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.d.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.r.e(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.r.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.v.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.c(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.view.bs.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What have you done so far to try to resolve the error?

Comment: I've tried to put -dontwarn for all those packages in progaurd file. But because of that the App is force quitting in the release apk.

Comment: There's a suspicious lack of Firebase in that list of errors. How did you determine it was related? Did you put the jar in your libs folder? Did you add it to your classpath? Did you watch [the video here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-quickstart.html)? Can you provide us some clues to understand your environment and setup, and narrow the possibilities by telling us what you've already tried?

Comment: @Kato I understood that its related by looking at the classes in the firebase jar. I've put the jar in libs folder just like other jars. I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Cool, how about the other things like adding it to the classpath? We'll need more than just the errors to see what's missing.

Comment: Included the log, please check that..

Comment: Post your proguard config file.

Comment: And the resulting proguard mapping.txt

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: 
In your project.properties, add this:

```
-dontwarn com.shaded.fasterxml.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.shaded.apache.**
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try add to 'proguard.cfg':

```
-injars bin/classes
-injars libs
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep class ____insert_your_package_lib_inside_jar_file.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that you have also included some libraries which depends on Java Servlets:

> can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.ServletContextListener

If so you won't be able to compile it under Android, since Servlet's need to be attached and properly dex'ed - I'm not sure that it's possible.

Android uses different bytecode standard which relies on Dalvik VM rather than Sun's JVM...